# myth or fact about functions in bash

Tags: bash

I understand that functions in bash are like `goto`'s in `c`, and this make the script a tiny bit slower. Is this true? Should I avoid or embrace functions?

```
function foo(){
bla..
}
```

Comment: Speed, in bash, should not be an issue. If it is, then use a compiled language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a `bash` script and worrying about the speed decrease a function call imposes, you're doing things wrong. Use a compiled language (like `c`)...

You should embrace functions for the following reasons:

- **Reusability**. You can call a function many times in your script. It's easier to call a function than it is to copy-and-paste the 10 lines to perform a task. It's easier to edit the task if it's located in one place, too.
- **abstraction**. When you've got a function, you can re-use it without caring how it works. (The function becomes a "black box").

I also find functions much easier to read - the function name should tell me what the code in the function does, and I can gain a high-level view of the code by looking at the functions, not the specific steps to complete that function.

Comment: I like your answer, I asked this question because I don't see often functions in bash script then I heard about the speed in bash and functions this is why I doubted it

Comment: Resuability:  not only is it easier to call a function 10 times, it is faster as well.  A function is compiled only once, if you cut/paste the code 10 times then it is compiled 10 times.